# Does data = batch['data'].cuda().function().cpu() make sense?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a dataset, which I call with batch['data'] and get my image output MxM. After I get my image I want to process it with some numpy operations. In this process I want my dataset to give me the image with GPU and changing the outputs device to CPU after that.

My question is, is concetanation of functions in Python being executed in an order? And can I make this process with

```
base = batch['data'].cuda().function().cpu()
```

And is this the same as:

```
base = batch['data'].cuda().function()
base.cpu()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the CPU(s) will do the same work, but the result is not the same.

```
base = batch['data'].cuda().cpu()
```

After that line, you have the output of `cpu()` stored in the variable called `base`.

```
base = batch['data'].cuda()
base.cpu()
```

After these two lines, you have the output of `cuda()` stored in the variable called `base` and you have forgotten the result of `cpu()`.

Answer (score 1):

> is concatenation of functions in Python being executed in an order?

Yes, of course: the first method returns some object, and the next one is called on that returned object.

No, these pieces of code are *not* the same:

1. The first one assigns the return value of `cpu` to `base`
2. The second one throws this value away

Also, if you need the object returned by `batch['data'].cuda()`, then the first code will call `cpu` on it *and potentially throw it away afterwards*. The second one saves that object but gets rid of the result of calling `cpu`, which may not be desirable

Same thing is with writing `batch['data'].cuda()` or `tmp = batch['data']; base = tmp.cuda()`: `batch['data']` returns some object, and then `.cuda` can be called on that object.

As long as functions return object that have the methods you want to call, you can chain as many methods as you want to: `thing().a().b().c().d()`

Comment: @Asil, I don't see where you're calling `base.cuda` or what `model` is

Comment: In this case base is a matrix gathered from dataset and model is a neural network model. In Deep Learning codes people use model.cuda() to put their model into GPU or model.cpu() to put into CPU. That works actually also in my code. I thought that would work for every object(matrix etc.)

Comment: @Asil, why would it work for all objects? Surely not _all_ objects have a method called `cuda`

Comment: @Asil the `cuda` method modifies an object which subclasses/inherits `torch.nn.Module` in place. For tensors it leaves the original unchanged and returns a copy.